# How to change the default url of Laravel 5 in windows

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I am making an application in Laravel 5.4. I am using xampp server in windows. I have to go in command prompt and start the server by command "php artisan serve". my default url is 127.0.0.1:8000. Is there any way that I can changed my default URl to something my computer IP 192.168.1.22/directory? and Is there a way that I do not need to start the server by php artisan serve?? I am new to Laravel and don't have much knowledge. Any help would be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use public link to access project without `php artisan serve`

```
http://192.168.1.22/laravel_project_name/public/
```

Answer (score 2):

use [laragon](https://laragon.org/) software for windows you can create pretty url like `http://app.test` or you can also set `192.168.1.22` to ip address

in laragon install process set mark to start when windows start so no need to start server manually

> laragon automatically create virtual host in windows it's protable

Answer (score -1):

Yes, You can create virtual host for laravel project.

Comment: Is there any guideline link to follow ??

Comment: https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/584/how-to-configure-a-virtual-host-for-a-laravel-project-in-xampp-for-windows